# FOSOAuthServerBundle + Amazon Alexa: How to manually authenticate user with Access Token?

Tags: symfony, authentication, oauth, fosoauthserverbundle

**In short**: How can I manually authenticate a users with a given access token?

**The long story:**

An Amazon Alexa Skill should access user data within a `Symfony 3.4` based web services.

The web services uses `FOSOAuthServerBundle` to handle the `OAauth` authentication and link the users Alexa account to the web services user account.

Once the account is linked Alexa API includes the OAuth Access Token in every request. However, the token is not included in the request header but simply within the JSON content. Additionally all request, both linked/authorized and not-linked/unauthorized call the same endpoint / route.

Thus using the Symfony firewall to authenticate the user does not work, does it?

Instead I manually check wether the Alexa request contains an access token to provide the correct response.

**If the request contains an access token I would need to manually check and authenticate the user. How can this be done?**